# Click Event in Silverlight User Control

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have user control in Silverlight which has a button click event.  When I add that user control to a page, the click event does not fire.  Is there something else I need to do?

**Update**
The user control by itself fires the click event.  When inside the page, it does not
Page

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="RadControlsSilverlightApp2.Page1" 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
       d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
       Title="Page1 Page" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" 

       xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:TestSilverLight.UserControls;assembly=TestSilverLight">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <sdk:Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="101,38,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Content="Test page" />

    <my1:Top10Programs HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="335,71,0,0" Name="top10Programs1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

User control

```
<UserControl x:Class="RadControlsSilverlightApp2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" BorderThickness="1"  xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail (code and/or Xaml). The description does not say how the user control implements the Button Click event.

Answer (score 1):

Have you raised an event in the usercontrol that is handled in the main page?

UserControl XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="133">
    <sdk:Label Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,31,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" Content="Name"  />
    <sdk:Label Content="Password" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,60,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,27,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,55,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253" />
    <Button Content="Login" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="161,101,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

UserControl code behind

```
public class userNameEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string userName{get;set;}
}

public partial class LoginBox : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<userNameEventArgs> LoggedIn;

    public LoginBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoggedIn(this, new userNameEventArgs(){userName=textBox1.Text});
    }
}
```

Mainpage XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button Content="Main Page" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,50,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <local:LoginBox Margin="100,122,179,223" LoggedIn="LoginBox_LoggedIn" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,376,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" />
</Grid>
```

Mainpage codebehind

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mainpage pressed!!");
    }

    private void LoginBox_LoggedIn(object sender, userNameEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = e.userName;
    }
}
```

This allows the text block on the main page to be updated when the button on the user control is clicked. It raises an event that is handled on the mainpage. The EventArgs tranfers the information between the user control and the mainpage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i am not looking to communicate between the main page and control. The user control is self contained

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the button is supposed to do? Have you added a click event in the user control xaml and code behind? See code segments 1 & 2 above. The click event in the user control doesn't have to raise an event. Does the mainpage have to do anything with the contents of the user control? Is it a popup that requires closing? Any more info you can share would help.  I see you have made some Telerik references; is the user control based on one of their containers?

Comment: Jason,  I just created a very simple user control it it had no problems firing the event.  I have to investigate why the other user control didnt fire.  thanks for you help. I gave you a ^ since it is very helpful